# Centering images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, align

I made my images in Ipe. But there are some not centered:
[image]

But, there are others centered:
[image]

I use the same code for both (just changing, of course, the files names):

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{m5c5f7}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

(it's .eps file). What should I do to change it? I also tried to put the 1st image centered in Ipe, but it didn't work.

Another thing that I tried to do it is to write `\hspace{6cm}\includegraphics[scale=1]{m5c5f7}`, but it didn't work either.

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the "pontos correspondentes..." paragraph part of the image? If it is, then I feel that the image is centered.

Comment: No, it's not haha @olga.saucedo

Comment: If that's truly the case, please, show us an MWE.

Comment: I never used IPE, but the reason can be that the bounding box of an .eps is wrong  (it happens with `pstricks` when pure graphics is mixed up with text. A solution consists un converting the .eps files to .pdf, with `epspdf` (or epspdftk``  under Windows). It converts with the help of GhostScript and crops the image to obtain an exact bounding box. Then you compile directly with `pdflatex`. The application is a `texlua` script available on CTAN.

Comment: I'm gonna try here @Bernard. Do you have any suggestion about another program to draw images? Thanks :)

Comment: I don't know well Tikz/Pgf, which is one of the possible solutions. Personally I use `pstricks`. It has many specialised extensions (e.g. `pst-eucl` for Euclidean plane geometry, `pst-poly` for all sorts of polygons, `pst-node`, pst-plot, &c.) and is well documented. It's an interface between LaTeX and PostScript, and nowadays can be compiled with |`pdflatex` if you load it with the `[pdf]` option. Take  a look at its home page to see what can be done with it: http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your centring efforts are almost certainly overkill here:

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
```

Generally you should only need two commands to centre images:

1. `\centering\includegraphics{...}` — when the figure is smaller than the text width
2. `\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}` — when the figure is wider than the text width

If this doesn't *appear* to centre your image correctly, put `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}` to see where the bounds of the image are; you may then need to either pad or crop the image to make it more symmetrical.

Comment: I'd avoid `\centerline{...}` and favor `\makebox[\textwidth]{...}`: `\centerline` isn't documented and it may have surprising effects.

Comment: @egreg — a matter of taste `:)` at least `\centerline` is somewhat semantic out of the box. I agree it's not the cleanest implementation, but it is memorable. I admit this is a controversial opinion of mine.

Comment: Actually, I just created another file and it worked haha but thanks anyway :)